# Signed hex subtraction vs unsigned

Tags: hex, unsigned, signed, subtraction

I have to do subtraction on two signed 16-bit hexadecimal numbers. C352 - 36AE. Whats the difference between signed and unsigned, when it comes to doing math with them? Is the only solution converting them to binary, performing signed subtraction, and then converting the answer back to hex? Thanks.

Comment: If they're 2's complement signed numbers, there's nothing special you have to do.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, they are two's complement. So assuming twos complement, doing the subtraction as signed would be the same answer as unsigned?

Comment: I did it as unsigned and got 8CA4. Not sure if signed will be the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is the same for both signed and unsigned.  What is different is how the results are interpreted.  Unsigned numbers can never be negative:

0xffff is -1  signed.
0xffff is 65,535 unsigned.

It's the same number.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 1):

The result of a 16 bit signed or unsigned subtraction is always 16 bits (being the result of bitwise subtraction) plus a 17th bit with the 17th bit being either the overflow bit (signed subtraction) or the carry bit (unsigned subtraction).  If you only have a 16 bit result you have a bitwise subtraction NOT a signed or unsigned 16 bit subtraction.  Instead of specifying signed, unsigned, or bitwise subtraction many systems produce all three results at once.  You later use the overflow bit if you intended signed subtraction, the carry bit if you intended unsigned subtraction, or neither for a bitwise subtraction.  Note that many people don't look at the 17th bit because they know from the range of inputs that they don't need a true 16 bit subtraction.  For instance if I subtract a number that I know to be between 0-100 from a number that I know to be between 1000-2000 I don't need a true 16 bit subtraction so I don't need to look at the 17th bit.  Note: Overflow and carry are derived by different rules and are NOT the same but the difference between the two has already been explained elsewhere so I won't duplicate that answer here.